# Kendo Scheduler not firing change event when you reselect

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I am having an issue with the kendo scheduler, the change event is not firing in a particular case.

When I select the calendar, let's Monday 23rd July to Friday 27th July. The change event fires with

```
Selection between 7/23/2018 12:00 AM and 7/27/2018 12:00 AM
```

Which is perfect, now if change my selection to be just Friday 27th July, the change event will not fire. Note that the change event will fire if I pick any other date that was previously selected. I need that change event to fire so I can update the dates that get sent back to the server. I don't know how to work around this.

It is the same scenario in their demo site: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/events

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

This is happening in the Month view

Comment: What view are you using? Are you making the selection using the mouse? Are you making the selection by click-and-dragging the all day slots or click-and-dragging over the regular slots?

Comment: @Shai I am in the month view. I am making the selection with the mouse, so click from monday to friday and then trying to select just friday is when the change event does not fire

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the scheduler itself. I think you should contact Telerik about it.